# Extending A PHP Class - Help Understanding

Tags: php, class, oop, extends

I am having a little trouble understanding how a class extends another. I have my model class.

```
class model{
    public $db;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->db = $GLOBALS['db']; 
    }

    public function _sel($table, $where="", $order_by="", $limit="", $group_by="",$database = NULL){            
        if($database === NULL) {  $database = $this->db; }
        // Yada Yada Yada
        $results = $database->select($sql);
    }
```

And I have a pagination class to extend it:

```
    class pagination extends model {

        public $limit;
        public $page;
        public $criteria;
        private $_totalRecords;
        private $_totalPages;   

        public function __construct(){  

            // Initialize
            $arguments = func_get_args();
            if(!empty($arguments)){
                foreach($arguments[0] as $key => $property){
                    if(property_exists($this, $key)){
                        $this->{$key} = $property;
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        public function getPaginationPage(){
          // Yada Yada Yada
          // This next line causes the issue
          $records = $this->_sel($query['table'],$query['where'],$query['order_by'],$start." , ".$end,$query['group_by'],$query['database']);
```

To keep this post short I tried to only include the necessary sections of code. The issue I am having is when I execute a query in the extended class it is failing because $this->db has no value. Since I set this in the constructor it seems to me that I need to call it again with something like $xx = new model() however since it's just an extension of a class that should already exist I am confused as to why it would not already have a value. Admittedly I am self taught and just starting to get into classes. Is my understanding of them wrong or is there just something I need to do make sure it "extends"?

Also this is how I am calling the extended class:

```
$this->model->pagination = new pagination(array(
            'limit'     =>  10,
            'page'      =>  1,
            'criteria'  => array('projects','status_id > 0','name ASC',''),         
        ));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have overwritten your `model` constructor in the `pagination` class. Simply call the *parent's* constructor from the *child's* constructor to retain both:

```
class pagination extends model {
    ...

    public function __construct() { 
        parent::__construct();
        ...
```

Comment: Thank you that works great. To make sure I completely understand if I call parent::__construct(); in an extended class will it reset any of the variables defined in the  parent __construct? For example if there was a function that was called and set $this->db = "Some new value" and then I call parent::__construct(); will $this->db = "Some new value" or $GLOBALS['db']; since that is what is defined in the __construct?

Comment: @user3167249 Your question is a little hard to follow, but I think you get it. The "last" constructor defined in the chain is the one that gets run, so if you want to ALSO run the constructor defined in the parent class, this is what you do. It's almost like calling `$this->someFunction()` except it happens to be the constructor, which has the same name as the function you're in, so you say `parent::__construct()` instead. And yes, the order of things does matter.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. So all variables defined in the parent construct will be set to the "initial value" defined in the parent construct and not retain any value they may have been changed to prior to calling parent::__construct()?

Comment: @user3167249 true statement